# How to access system environment variables using Python

Tags: python

I am aware that you can use `os.environ['key']` to access an environment variable, but it appears that this function is localized to environment variables for the signed in user. I need to access the system environment variables. Is this possible?

Comment: For example, which "system environment variable", that's not in the signed in user's environment?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @martineau Windows.

Comment: In that case you can probably do it by making one or more calls to the Windows API using the `ctypes` module. In addition there's Python Interfaces to many system-level functions in the PyWin32 extension already written. Lastly, some versions of Windows support a `setx` command that accesses system-level environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using `os.environ` in python. You can, however, use `os.system` to run a commands such as:

```
sudo -Hiu $user env | grep $var
```

to access a variable from another user. This is a bit hacky, but it works. And your options are limited here.

Also -- why do you want to? You should have a process for setting the environment variables before this script is run at all, ideally.